# Pandas select which rows to read JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge `JSON` file (lots of smaller `.log` (`JSON` format) files combined together to a total of 8Gb), composed of **multiple different objects** (where every object takes a row). I want to read this file into a `pandas dataframe`. I am only interested in collecting the `JSON` entries for **one specific object** (this would drastically reduce the file size to read). Can this be done with `pandas` or `python` before reading in a `dataframe`?

**My current code is as follows:**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df = pd.concat([pd.read_json(f, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", lines=True) for f in glob.glob("logs/sample1/*.log")], ignore_index=True)
```

As you might imagine, this is very computationally heavy, and takes a lot of time to complete. Is there a way to process this before reading it in a `dataframe`?

**Sample of Data:**

```
{"Name": "1","variable": "value","X": {"nested_var": 5000,"nested_var2": 2000}}
{"Name": "2","variable": "value","X": {"nested_var": 1222,"nested_var2": 8465}}
{"Name": "2","variable": "value","X": {"nested_var": 123,"nested_var2": 865}}
{"Name": "1","variable": "value","X": {"nested_var": 5500,"nested_var2": 2070}}
{"Name": "2","variable": "value","X": {"nested_var": 985,"nested_var2": 85}}
{"Name": "2","variable": "value","X": {"nested_var": 45,"nested_var2": 77}}
```

I want to only read instances where `name = 1`

Comment: Is possible add some data sample of json?

Comment: @jezrael Please check my edit, I have included a dummified sample of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loop by each file, each line and append filtered rows to list, last use `DataFrame` contructor:

```
data = []
for file in glob.glob('logs/*.json'):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if json.loads(line)['Name'] == '1':
                data.append(json.loads(line))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this have any difference in terms of execution speeds when compared to the my method?

Comment: @DavidFarrugia - Really hard question, it depends of data, the best test it.

Comment: True. I will test this. I will mark this as the answer since it does what I requested. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael how to write solution using `np.repeat(df[['col1','col2']],repeats=df['col3'].str.len())` for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352226/repeating-the-rows-of-a-data-frame)