# Expanding the rows of a data frame based on its column containing lists

Tags: python, pandas

My original data -

```
pd.DataFrame([
        {'col1': 1, 'col2': 11, 'col3': ['A', 'B'] },
        {'col1': 2, 'col2': 22, 'col3': ['P', 'Q', 'R'] },
    ])
```

which gives me -

```
   col1  col2          col3
0     1    11          ['A', 'B']
1     2    22     ['P', 'Q', 'R']
```

I'd like to expand the rows depending on contents of the array in `col3` i.e. I'd like to get a `dataframe` like this one -

```
    col1  col2 col3
0     1    11   'A'
1     1    11   'B'
2     2    22   'P'
3     2    22   'Q'
4     2    22   'R'
```

What's a good way accomplishing this? I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352226/repeating-the-rows-of-a-data-frame/52352487#52352487) however it doesn't include `col3` in the output.

I also have another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows) however since it has strings in the column. The same solution wouldn't work here because `split()` wouldn't work for `list`.